# SFTP connection is getting closed after password

Tags: ssh, cygwin

We have set up Cygwin on Windows 2012 and the services related to the tool are running fine on the server.

During installation we have created a local user cyg_server, we tried to create home folder with cyg_server using `sftp cyg_server@servername` but in this case when we try to do `sftp -v cyg_server@servername` it is prompting for the password which we have entered and the connection established home it immediately getting closed with the below result.

details

```
ssh -v cyg_server@fn002dataaege-n.fn.ae.ge.com
OpenSSH_4.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7i 14 Oct 2005
debug1: Reading configuration data /opt/LTIssh/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to fn002dataaege-n.fn.ae.ge.com [3.14.136.107] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'fn002dataaege-n.fn.ae.ge.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/known_hosts:2035
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /export/home/chettigo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
cyg_server@fn002dataaege-n.fn.ae.ge.com's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
Last login: Thu Feb 26 06:23:07 2015 from gpsgc304.corporate.ge.com
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to fn002dataaege-n.fn.ae.ge.com closed.
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 52 bytes in 17.6 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 3.0
debug1: Exit status 1
```

How can I debug and resolve this issue?

Comment: can you connect using WinSCP? it may provide more meaningful logs. From what I'm seeing in your logs, the failure is there, but no information as to the cause, which looks like it dumped to stdErr. you can try redirecting stderr to a file, with: `ssh -v cyg_server@fn002dataaege-n.fn.ae.ge.com 2> error.log`. after it fails look at ~/error.log and see if there is more meaningful debug info on the failure.

Comment: in the event logs i could see the event id as 0 and the description as below

Comment: The description for Event ID 0 from source sshd cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

sshd: PID 4376: syslogin_perform_logout: logout() returned an error

Comment: I'd try testing your configuration using PuTTY or WinSCP, to confirm that the server is working correctly.

Comment: tried with different client putty as well as secure shell i get the same result, am able to give the password but it gets immediate disconnect

Comment: could anyone please help here ?

Comment: did you run the command in my first comment, and then check the log of STDErr? Not the event log.

Comment: i have run the command ssh -v cyg_server@fn002dataaege-n.fn.ae.ge.com on cygwin bash below are the results that it displayed

Comment: The description for Event ID 0 from source sshd cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event:  sshd: PID 4660: syslogin_perform_logout: logout() returned an error

Answer (score 1):

In your account shell initialization scripts, I have found that if there is **ANY** output being sent to stdout then `scp`/`sftp` fails in the way you describe.

What you have to do is check all files on the remote host including:

- account specific `.cshrc`, `.login`, `.bashrc`, `.env`, `.profile`
- global initialization files in `/etc` such as `bashrc`, `csh.cshrc`, `csh.login`